# I think a definition is wrong in "Model Categories" by Hovey.

Tags: general-topology, definition

I am working through the book "Model Categories", by Mark Hovey, and have a doubt about a definition given there. At the beginning of page 50 we read:

> Define a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to be a *closed $T_1$ inclusion* if $f$ is a closed inclusion and if every point **not** in $Y\backslash f(X)$ is closed in $Y$.

The bold "**not**" is the part troubling me. First of all, it seems strange in the phrasing of the definition. Personally I would have stated it as "if every point in $f(X)$". Second, a couple of pages later (p.52, corollary 2.4.6) he proves that some maps are closed $T_1$ inclusions by showing that every point **in** $Y\backslash f(X)$ is closed.

I am quite convinced that the "**not**" doesn't belong to the definition, but I would like a second opinion about that. Also, there is no correction about that definition in the errata at the end of the book. If this is effectively an error, what should I do? Try to contact AMS to tell them?

Comment: You probably should contact them. This isn't the first time that there's a typo in the textbook.

Comment: The official errata for the book has been posted [here](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Hovey/model-err.pdf).

Comment: I'd recommend that you contact Hovey directly, not the AMS (Hovey's at [Wesleyan](http://www.wesleyan.edu/mathcs/whoswho/index.html) and his email address is easy to find). Instead of sending each typo/potential mistake separately, I would collect a few of them and send them as a bundle. Hovey is a nice person and will surely appreciate that you read his book attentively. Try to be diplomatic anyway: it's always better to request clarifications on your confusions or ask questions than to point out errors or wrong definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP is correct that this is a typo. The word "not" should be omitted. Hovey's definition of "closed $T_1$ inclusion" in his paper [Monoidal Model Categories](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=7E021EF2C487C68D617A265D854F713B?doi=10.1.1.178.4157&rep=rep1&type=pdf) corrects this, saying "every point of $Y$ not in $f(X)$ is closed, i.e., every point in $Y \backslash f(X)$. That latter definition is what is actually proven in 2.4.5 and 2.4.6 of his book, and matches definitions of later authors building on Hovey's work, e.g., [Gaucher](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.3553.pdf).